# send email periodically from a specific time django celery

Tags: django-celery

I've list of activities in my django model. I need to send email to user for every 15 min until the activity(if activity status: High) completes.

Steps I followed:

1.created celery task

2.triggered this task using apply_async(eta='time object')

3.I registered this task in CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE

```
#1.celery task
@shared_task
def periodic_send_email(self, *args, **kwargs):
   #Logic for sending email

#2.task triggering
periodic_send_email.apply_async(eta= "I used time object", retry= True)

#3.registering the task in settings:
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'periodic_send_email': {
    'task': 'cloud_app.tasks.periodic_send_email',
    'schedule': crontab(),
},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starting scheduler; http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler

Crontab schedulers; http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules

You don't need task trigger. You should set crontab as `crontab(minute="*/15")`

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'periodic_send_email': {
    'task': 'cloud_app.tasks.periodic_send_email',
    'schedule': crontab(minute="*/15"),
},
}
```

And, you must be started celery with `-B` parameter.
First, start celery worker with command;

```
celery -A proj worker -B
```

After, start celery beat;

```
celery -A proj beat
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is not the problem with crontab(), I'm just testing it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My task is: Suppose one activity has to be started at specific time. The person who started activity will change the activity status from Open to In progress. I've to check the activity status and if the status is still Not started at that time, then I've to send mails periodically for every 15 or 20 minutes. I've tried to trigger the task in signals (when ever activity created or updated) used apply_async(args, kwargs ,eta). I'm sending instance in kwargs to the task above I mentioned. In second beat task is taking args, kwargs from the CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE. pls help..

Answer (score 0):

I've got one.
we can use Database-backed Periodic Tasks.
package: django-celery-beat

https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

in admin panel we can create periodic task with specific interval and we can store args, kwargs as well.